# webpack 2 - Angular 2 - Dynamic Loading Of Routes - Dynamic Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, webpack-2

Using webpack 2.1.0-beta.25 and Angular 2.1.

I want to be able to load a route from a config.json file and at runtime load that route along with it's components into the angular 2 app.

I had success in webpack 1 and the older version of angular2 using require.ensure() to generate a separate bundle for the dynamically loaded components.

What is the best way to accomplish this with webpack 2 and angular 2.1?

Thanks